# How do I remap GUI menu popup in emacs to cycle between items?

Tags: emacs, binding

I've been trying to find the function that cycles between items whitout any success.

By default the bindings are: C-n, Down arrow for next item and C-p, Up arrow for previous item.

The GUI menu popup: menu-bar-open for example has arrows keys bindings, I would like to change them.

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you call a GUI menu pop-up and provide a better description of what you mean by cycling in that particular example.  The question will likely be better suited for superuser.com  Also, please state what operating system and whether your usage of the word GUI means that you are not using the terminal.

Comment: Ok.. I'm using Arch Linux as OS, emacs with Graphical User Interface enabled, as the image shows the popup menu displayed is the default menu you get with menu-bar-open function. I just want to change the bindings to cycle between options of this menu.